# Search a date in multiple date ranges and return the corresponding value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, date-range

In sheet 1, I have a list of dates in Column A in chronological order. There are values corresponding to this list in Column B. There is another list of dates in sheet 2 and I want to add values from sheet 1 to these dates.

```
Sheet 1.

     **Column A       Column B
      DATE            Amount**
1.  10/01/2015      25,60,000
2.  10/02/2015      26,80,000
3.  01/03/2015      21,55,000
4.  30/03/2015      24,60,500
5.  30/04/2015      28,20,000
6.  30/06/2015      19,00,000

Sheet 2.

     Column A      Column B
1.  21/02/2015     21,55,000
2.  15/01/2015
3.  20/05/2015
4.  25/04/2015
```

For example: I need to look up 21/02/2015 in sheet 1 and column A and return the value corresponding to the next available date. So for 21/02/2015 I need the value corresponding to the next date available which is 01/03/2015 and the value is 21,55,000. If its 15/01/2015 I need the value of 10/02/2015 i.e. 26,80,000

What formula could I use for this?

Comment: Would you be willing to do this in VBA or do you explicitly need a formula?

Comment: Formula would be the first priority, but if that's too hard, I have no problem with VBA either

Comment: One more: The data in Sheet 2, Column 1 is not sorted?

Comment: nope.. is it required anyway?

Comment: It would make things easier, but it'll work without being sorted.

Comment: so how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You could use VLOOKUP, but it has some issues. So it is better to use INDEX and MATCH combination. In your case try this

```
=INDEX('Sheet 1'!$B:$B,MATCH(A1,'Sheet 1'!$A:$A,-1))
```

---

Sorry, my previous answer works only for descending order. Try this instead

```
=INDEX('Sheet 1'!$B:$B,MATCH(TRUE,('Sheet 1'!$A:$A-A1)=MIN(IF('Sheet 1'!$A:$A-A1>=0,'Sheet 1'!$A:$A-A1)),0))
```

---

Explanation: I hope that [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) and [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/MATCH-function-E8DFFD45-C762-47D6-BF89-533F4A37673A) are well explained in Office Support.

About the condition:

```
('Sheet 1'!$A:$A-A1)=MIN(IF('Sheet 1'!$A:$A-A1>=0,'Sheet 1'!$A:$A-A1))
```

What it means?

```
'Sheet 1'!$A:$A-A1
```

results in a difference between the value in the cell `A1` and the cell in A column in Sheet 1.

```
MIN(IF('Sheet 1'!$A:$A-A1>=0,'Sheet 1'!$A:$A-A1))
```

says that if the difference is non-negative (`'Sheet 1'!$A:$A-A1>=0`), find the minimum of such numbers (MIN function).

And if these numbers are equal (MATCH function), then pick the corresponding number in column B (`INDEX('Sheet 1'!$B:$B,...)`).

---

Apology: In my previous answers I swapped the columns of your example. I hope it is now correct.

Comment: I did not understand, Kindly explain

Comment: Sorry, I do not have Excel on me right now, so I cannot try the code. Please, let me know, if it works and if it is now more understandable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, unfortunately its still not working and is giving #N/A Error. I couldn't figure out the problem, please tell me if you did.

Comment: Can you tell me, what happens, if you try subtract a date from another date, e.g. `=A2-A1` ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vlookup with True rather than the widely used form with False

Comment: It only gives me the value for prior to the looked up date

Answer (score 0):

As ExcelEfendisi said you can use vlookup with range lookup enabled. A  simple way to get the value at the next date rather than the prior one would be to push all the amount values down one row, but to avoid that it might be better to repeat the index values - like this

```
1   10/01/15    25,60,000   1  
2   10/02/15    26,80,000   2  
3   01/03/15    21,55,000   3  
4   30/03/15    24,60,500   4  
5   30/04/15    28,20,000   5  
6   30/06/15    19,00,000   6
```

Then you can use two vlookups, the first one to get the index of the row with the date prior to the date you are interested in and a second one to extract the balance value for the subsequent date - not very elegant but it would work

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula *(enter in `Sheet2` cell `B2` then copy till the last record)*

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,1+MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,1),1)
```

As data is sorted in ascending order use `MATCH` with `match type 1 (less than)` to obtain the `row` above the *high next* item, then add 1 and the result is  the *high next row*, use this `row` to get the corresponding record from the column `B` with formula `INDEX`