# ABS formula not working with Date value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I was trying answer **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548569/excel-how-to-search-a-date-in-multiple-date-ranges-and-return-the-correspondin)** question here on SO, but I noticed that **`ABS`** formula is NOT working with certain Date value. I am not getting why it's working with certain dates and not with others.

Can please someone explain me what's going on here?

Here is the screenshot to show what I've tried.

[image]

*** Note**: The dates are in `"dd/mm/yyyy"` format and I don't want to make any changes in column `A`.

Comment: any chance excel is thinking that column A dates are supposed to be mm/dd/yy. The rejected ones are all invalid mm/dd dates. What locale u in?

Comment: I thought same and that's the reason I've tried `TEXT` formula in column `C` and `E` but no luck.

Comment: Try this experiment: Give column `B` number formatting of `general`. Then put formula in `B2` `=A2` and copy down. Anything revealing?

Comment: If you try that experiment, my guess is that the 'dates' causing errors are really text.

Comment: those are not valid dates in column A. Note that they have not been recognised (not right justified). Change them to mm/dd/yy

Comment: Oops. I should have said give the column number formatting of `number` instead of `general` for the experiment. Sorry.

Comment: you text columns dont do anything. If the input is not a number or a date it just returns the input

Comment: @ExcelHero even number formats are not able translate dates in row 5,6,7,8 and 10 to numbers. They are still as is.

Comment: That is correct. Exactly what I suspected. Those dates in row 5,6,7,8 and 10 are not dates. THEY ARE TEXT.

Comment: @pm100 I've tried to convert the dates to `mm/dd/yyyy` in column `E` but it didn't work.

Comment: If they were true dates, they would format as numbers... because dates are numbers.

Comment: col E does nothing to invalid dates. fix column A

Comment: Both pm100 and I are saying the same thing. Some of your `dates` are not dates. They were entered wrongly as text.

Comment: @pm100 I can change in column `A`, but lets say I've been given the data in this format only.

Comment: Sorry but I have to ask. Why do you need to apply the `ABS` formula to a date, a date is positive always. `ABS` definition: Returns the absolute value of a number. The absolute value of a number is the number without its sign.

Comment: @EEM as I said in my question, I was trying to answer one question and came across this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data have been given to you in this format and since some of the dates are true numeric dates and some are text that look like dates, you will need to massage the data so that all are true numeric dates before proceeding.

Here is a formula that you can place in column B that should do it:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,2)>"31",A2,DATE(RIGHT(A2,4),MID(A2,4,2),LEFT(A2,2)))
```

This formula is making the assumption that all of the values in column A that are really text but look like dates are in this exact format: mm/dd/yyyy.

Also, the comparison to "31" at the beginning of the formula means that this should work for all dates AFTER the year 1987.

Comment: Last minute question, how can I format the date (30/03/2015) to show a date in `"dd/mm/yyyy"` format?

Comment: like in my screenshot cell A5 is showing as text even though I've tried to format that cell as date.

Comment: Well once you have used my formula to massage the data, all of those dates will now be true numbers. Not in column A, but in column B (if that is where you used the formula). Now just apply the dd/mm/yyyy number format to column B.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89617/discussion-between-nelly27281-and-excel-hero).

Answer (score 1):

*It seems to me that this problem has not been solved, as the real cause of the problem was not identified, so I’m posting this in order to raise awareness about the cause of the issue.*

The real issue is not that some dates are invalid *(thought they are actually text and not serial numbers representing a particular date)*, the problem is that the computer used to process the input file *(not necessarily same as the one in use when this issue was identified)* was expecting dates in the *american* notation *(mm/dd/yyyy)*, and all these dates are in *international* notation *(dd/mm/yyyy)*.

As @Nelly27281 stated

> Note: The dates are in "dd/mm/yyyy" format and I don't want to make
>   any changes in column A.

However looking at all the values that apparently are correct in `[A2:A4,A9]`, notice that these dates are represented as text are showing what is expected to be days as months and vice versa in `[C2:C4,C9]` (see Fig. below)

[image]
Fig. 1

*It is indeed strange to have a mix a date formats coming from the same source.*

This actually means that the format of the cells `[A2:A4,A9]` is something like `m/d/yyyy`

As per the above it seems that the actual values (intended ones - coming probably from an external file) are:

[image] 
Fig. 2

To replicate the issue change the `Region` settings to format the `Short date` as `MM/dd/yyyy` and format the cells `A2:A10` as `m/d/yyyy`. Then enter the list of dates in these cells, you will notice that the dates in `A5:A8,A10` are entered as text. This is because the system is expecting dates as `mm/dd/yyyy` and the first part of those inputs are > 12 *(not qualifying as months)* so the values entered are not recognized as dates and as they contain non-numeric characters they are taken as labels *(text or string)*.

Based on the above *(which should be validated against the source data)* the following formula returns the correct dates assuming:

1. That any `numeric` date was converted as `m/d/yyyy` actually been `d/m/yy`
2. Any `text` date should be converted as date using the format `d/m/yy`.

`=IF(ISNUMBER($A2),
DATE(YEAR($A2),DAY($A2),MONTH($A2)),
DATE(RIGHT($A2,4),SUBSTITUTE(MID($A2,1+FIND("/",$A2),2),"/",""),
SUBSTITUTE(LEFT($A2,2),"/","")))`

*(enter in B2 then copy till the last record)*